# How to concatenate two variables in a array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am pushing values to a empty array using push(), but when I console log the array I am getting a single character per line. I am trying to concatenate two variables into one line/space.

```
// Example
walking.CordX = 5;
walking.CordY = 2;

walking.wLog.push("x" + " " + walking.cordX, "y" + " " + walking.cordY);

console.log(wLog);
```

//Will Show

```
1: x5
2: y2
```

How can I change it to get it like:

```
1: x5 y2
```

Comment: `"x" + " " + walking.cordX + " " +  "y" + " " + walking.cordY` maybe?

Comment: Perfect, solved it, I guess removing the comma and adding a space, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use multi-line syntax from es6.

```js
let arr = [], x=5, y=7;

arr.push(`x${x} y${y}`);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I think it is called: "Template Strings"

Answer (score 1):

```
walking.wLog.push("x" + " " + walking.cordX + " " + "y" + " " + walking.cordY);
```

This should work.